# AWS Lambda Function Does Not Show Access to DynamoDb

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am doing [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-create-an-aws-iam-policy-to-grant-aws-lambda-access-to-an-amazon-dynamodb-table/) AWS tutorial to create an AWS policy and role for a Lambda function to have access to a DynamoDb. After I add the roles to the Lambda function I should get a diagram like this one from the tutorial:

[image]

This is what I get:

[image]

Comment: But does not work? Sometimes console doesn't show all the permissions added manually to its exec role.

Comment: I did not go further because the drawing is not accurate. The tutorial does it all manually.

Comment: Could be worth checking? If not, can you post your execution role. Maybe there is some issue there after all.

Comment: @Marcin You are right. It does execute. Thanks.

Comment: Cool. I will make an answer then for future reference if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The lambda **function works** as expected. Sometimes console will not display all the resources it has access to. This does not mean that it can't access the required resources though.

Thus its better to check and see if it actually work despity of what console shows.